# $a_n = 2n^2, n \geq 1$ (modified)

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

The puzzle asks to determine the next term in the sequence 2, 4, 8, 0, 0, 16...

a. 32
b. 18
c. 20
d. 24
e.  0

The obvious answer for me would be 32, with these zeros serving as the "neutral element" of the sequence. But I feel uncomfortable because it's almost like discarding them to produce a sequence like  2, 4, 8, 0, 0, 16, 32, 64, 0, 0, 128, 256, ...

Is there some closed formula or logic to determine the next term? Maybe a<sub>n</sub> = 0, n mod 5 = 0?

([Source (pg. 182)](https://www.amazon.com.br/Sequences-Applications-Communication-Information-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B08N6RMG9C/ref=sr_1_3?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=sequences+matemhatics&qid=1605452305&sr=8-3-spell))

Comment: What does the title refer to? Does the puzzle ask to modify 2n^2 to get 2, 4, 8, 0, 0, 16... that continues to one of a.-e. answers?

Comment: I feel like the question needs more information/context to be answerable. I agree the pattern of numbers/gaps could be 3-2-3-2..., but I was more interested in the fact the numbers could be decreasing: we only get 3-2-1. So maybe the pattern is 3-2-1-3-2-1... Or maybe something else entirely! It's not really clear (at least to me)

Comment: Without looking at the source,this could also be a linear recurrence $a_{n+3}=2 a_n - a_{n+1}$. Then the next number would be $0$.

Comment: It seems the answer is not given in your book. This is not a book dedicated to puzzles but to data communication and information security. This puzzle must be related to the chapter it belongs to. What is that chapter about?

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> 0

Reasoning

> For $n \geq 3$, the numbers seem to follow the recursive relationship $$a_{n} = 16 - a_{n-1} - 2a_{n-2}$$ In particular, $$8 = 16 - 4 - (2\times 2) $$ $$0 = 16 - 8 - (2\times 4) $$ $$0 = 16 - 0 - (2\times 8) $$ $$16 = 16 - 0 - (2\times 0) $$ and finally $$0 = 16 - 16 - (2\times 0) $$